# How can I select sqlite "check ... in [list]" options in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Pretty much everything is in the title.
I'm looking for an SQLite equivalent of the following SQL command :

`show columns from users where field = "category";`

Given that the show statement doesn't exist in SQLite.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use meta data held in SQLite with query:

```
select
  sm.name as table_name,
  pti.name as column_name
from
  sqlite_master sm
join
  pragma_table_info(sm.name) as pti
where
  pti.name like '%category%';
```

It returns (as can be seen) tables with column names. Then, you can filter output by column name, I used for example condition:

```
where pti.name like '%category%'
```

which returns only those column names including `category`.

Comment: I get returned this : 


array:1 [▼
  0 => {#1142 ▼
    +"table_name": "defis"
    +"column_name": "category"
  }
]

 That is just the column and table name.
I wanted to access all the possible values of that given column [check 'category' in('foo', 'bar', ...) data structure]

Comment: Well ok maybe the sql equivalent was wrong. 
Better version : 
"select
  category
from
  defi
group by
  category"

But in a way that would return all possible options (from enum)